# SSIS: IF else in Derived Column expressions

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl, derived-column

I am trying to convert the way time is written in the flat file source so it would actually look like time.(If that makes any sense).

Right now I have it as `1215`, `630`, `10`, `1` ,.. etc. So it can be 4-1 character long, so I need to convert it depending on the length of the column.

I am doing this in Derived Column with an expression, however I can't seem to make it work, not sure if my syntax is wrong or what, the expression looks like this, however I'm getting errors:

```
(LEN([TIME OCC]) == 4) ? (SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],1,2) + ":" +  SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],3,2)) : (LEN([TIME OCC]) == 3) ? (SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],1,1) + ":" + SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],2,2)) : (LEN([TIME OCC]) == 2) ? (SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],1,2) + ":00") : (LEN([TIME OCC]) == 1) ? (SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],1,1) + ":00")
```

When I do it with only two values like below it seems to work perfectly:

```
LEN([TIME OCC]) == 3 ? SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],1,1) + ":" + SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],2,2) : SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],1,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],3,2)
```

I would appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: "The expression might contain an invalid token, an incomplete token, or an invalid element. It might not be well-formed, or might be missing part of a required element such as a parenthesis"  - I've tried a bunch of different ways of writing the expression and none of them seem to work.

Comment: does `10` mean `00:10`? The simplest thing to do would be to left pad with zeros then split and put the `:` in. Then you don't need a great big nested expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ending your expression with an incomplete ternary expression.  I am adding some line breaks and indentation to make it more readable:

```
(LEN([TIME OCC]) == 4) ? 
(SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],1,2) + ":" +  SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],3,2)) : 
  (LEN([TIME OCC]) == 3) ? 
  (SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],1,1) + ":" + SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],2,2)) : 
    (LEN([TIME OCC]) == 2) ? 
    (SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],1,2) + ":00") : 
      (LEN([TIME OCC]) == 1) ? 
      (SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],1,1) + ":00")  <-- there needs to be a : with an ELSE condition here
```

I don't know if it's necessary, but I would also put a set of parenthesis around each of the nested ternary expressions.

Comment: I tried making the last part into the ELSE condition and tried adding additional one still no luck. And parenthesis did not help either. Gonna try out anything, now.

Comment: Edit your post and add what you tried, so we can maybe spot the error.

Comment: Why pick the most complicated error prone solution? I guess I should get overit

Answer (score 4):

All these answers are too complicated. Way too complicated. To me this is far less complicated:

```
LEFT(RIGHT(("0000" + [TIME OCC]),4),2) + 
":" +
RIGHT(RIGHT(("0000" + [TIME OCC]),4),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Tab says, missing the final alternative, try this:

```
LEN([TIME OCC]) == 4 ? (DT_WSTR,2)SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],1,2) + ":" + (DT_WSTR,2)SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],3,2) 
: LEN([TIME OCC]) == 3 ?(DT_WSTR,1)SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],1,1) + ":" + (DT_WSTR,2)SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],2,2) 
: LEN([TIME OCC]) == 2 ? (DT_WSTR,2)SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],1,2) + ":00"  
: (DT_WSTR,1)SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],1,1) + ":00"
```

assuming the last alternative with a length 1.

I hope this help.

Comment: I don't know if it was the type casts that I was missing, but this worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Derrived column is the best way to solve your issue (*it may be more complicated*). you can add a Script component and mark your column as input, create a new output Column (*Type DT_STR*) and use the following code inside the `OutpoutBuffer0_ProcessInputRow` method:

*Assuming that `TIMEOCC` and `outColumn` are your input and output column*

```
If Not row.TIMEOCC_IsNull AndAslo _
   Not String.IsnullorEmpty(Row.TIMEOCC.trim) Then

   Select Case Row.TIMEOCC.Trim.Length

   Case 1

         Row.OutColumn = Row.TIMEOCC & ":00"
   Case 2

         Row.OutColumn = Row.TIMEOCC & ":00"
   Case 3

         Row.OutColumn = Row.TIMEOCC.Substring(0,1) & ":" & Row.TIMEOCC.Substring(1,2)
   Case 4

         Row.OutColumn = Row.TIMEOCC.Substring(0,2) & ":" & Row.TIMEOCC.Substring(2,2)
   Case Else

          Row.OutColumn = "00:00"
   End Select

Else

    Row.OutColumn = "00:00"

End If
```

**If you want your solution by derrived column only**

i think this is what you are looking for:

```
     ISNULL([TIME OCC]) ? "00:00" 
: (LEN([TIME OCC]) == 4 ? ((DT_WSTR,2)SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],1,2) + ":" + (DT_WSTR,2)SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],3,2)) 
: (LEN([TIME OCC]) == 3 ?((DT_WSTR,2)SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],1,1) + ":" + (DT_WSTR,2)SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],2,2))
: (LEN([TIME OCC]) == 2 ? ((DT_WSTR,2)SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],1,2) + ":00")  
: (LEN([TIME OCC]) == 1 ? ((DT_WSTR,2)SUBSTRING([TIME OCC],1,1) + ":00")
: "00:00"))))
```

**References**

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/48372e18-598b-4005-9ed8-7ccc8bba30ae/how-to-write-case-statement-in-ssis-expression-using-derived-column-transformation-available-in-bi?forum=sqlintegrationservices
- https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1456697-148-1.aspx
- [How to write SSIS switch/case expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686166/how-to-write-ssis-switch-case-expression)